# Return data instead of promise from node

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I am new to node and just start build my first backend service.

What I am trying to do here is pretty simple, I got a auth code from client side and will use this data to fetch account information from a stripe API then it will send it back to client for further use.

The problem is, the response I got is always a resolved promise instead of promise value, when I log this response in client side I can see the data in promise value, how can I get that data?

Here's the code

```
const app2 = express();
app2.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app2.post('/', (req, res) => {

let options = {
  url: 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token',
  method: 'POST',
  body:req.body
};

function fetchToken(opt) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(opt,(err, tokenRes, body) => {
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(body) ;
    })
  })
}

fetchToken(options).then(data => {
  console.log(data)
  return(res.send(data));
}).catch(e => console.log(e))

}

exports.connectHelper = functions.https.onRequest(app2);
```

from what I understand, the promise is working properly and the res.send() did wait for promise. But why is it still sent the promise? What makes me even more confusing is that the `console.log(data)` right above `res.send(data)` did log the right account information in cloud function log viewer.

---

Here's my client side code, which is pretty straight forward

```
fetch(connectHelper,{
  method: 'POST',
  body: authCode,
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res.json())
})
```

Comment: Might not be the problem, but you should definitely add `return` to the `reject(err)` line, otherwise in case of error, you will call both `reject` and `resolve` which might cause strange things to happen... Also I would suggest to add some static parameter (number) to your `console.log` statements, so you can be sure, which one was fired.

Comment: "*when I log this response in client side I can see the data in promise value*" - if that is your actual problem, please show us your clientside code that logs the response. It seems you are using promises there as well - but those have nothing to do with the promise chain on your server. It's a promise that resolves when a http response is received from the server, regardless of its implementation.

Comment: @MartinAdámek Calling both won't cause strange things to happen, a promise can be resolved only once. But yes, an `else` or `return` would be better style.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bergi 's comment, I double check my client side code and the problem did actually comes from there.

I change from

```
fetch(connectHelper,{
  method: 'POST',
  body: authCode,
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res.json())
})
```

to

```
fetch(
  connectHelper,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    body: authCode,
  }).then(res => {
    res.json()
    .then(data => ({data:data}))
    .then(res => {
       console.log(res.data)
  })
})
```

and it log the object instead of promise now!